# Wordpress 404 Customize/edit post/edit pages - Cpanel/Host issue?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-theme-astra

I have a 404 not found error when I click on "customize", "editor", or try and edit any post or page. The problem also occurs when I try to enable the Astra Pro "new header/footer customizer".

It is not a theme or plugin related problem. I have changed themes and eliminated all plugins. Even if I create a brand new WP site thru Cpanel the problem will exist on that site as well. This leads me to believe it's a host/cpanel side issue or some change made in the plugin update.

The problem goes away with Ultimate Addons for Gutenberg v 1.25.6.  If I upgrade to any newer version of this plugin all the way up to 2.0.15 which is now Spectra then I get the issue. Brainstorm force who are the makers of the Astra theme and the Gutenberg/Spectra plugin have been trying to figure this out for 2 months and I'm losing patience.

1. switched themes - same issue
2. Created brand new WP site via Cpanel and installed only Astra and Spectra - same issue on new site
3. Roll back to UA for Gutenberg 1.25.6 - problem goes away
4. Update UA for Gutenberg to 2.0.0 thru 2.0.15 - problem comes back
5. Tried the fixes previously described on this forum - same issue

Comment: Sounds like a host issue

Comment: Did some additional testing on a brand new WP installation. I can use the newest version of Spectra IF I do not activate their Astra theme.

Comment: I use astra with elementor so I can't really tell what the issue is with Spectra. However I did find this on wpastra's website. Depending on your theme version you might want to add this to your functions.php

https://wpastra.com/docs/improved-spectra-compatibility/#user-experience:

Comment: No luck with that.  It's just so weird that /wp-admin/customize.php works and then once the plugin is updated it doesn't work anymore.  There's nothing in their update release notes that would help figure it out either. I don't know enough about plugin coding to try and dive into anything.

Comment: Thats weird. Send me the version of both your theme and the plugins you use. I'll see what I can do

Comment: astra 3.9.4 and any version of gutenberg 2.0.0 up to spectra 2.0.16

Comment: I tested this on a fresh installation with only the Astra theme and Spectra latest release and I do not encounter any errors.

Comment: Can't say I'm surprised since I seem to be the only one with this problem. I guess it points back to the host then https://www.surpasshosting.com/

I opened a ticket with them, waiting to hear back

Comment: Well, the provider fixed it.  Was a modsecurity problem as someone mentioned somewhere else.

Comment: . From the looks of the apache error logs, it would appear that you are getting blocked from using the widgets due to the response body being too large. This is the following log displayed:

We have included the domain within the ModSecurity rules. Please indicate if the exception has now allowed you to access the widget.

Comment: Ah that explains glad you found the solution